# Is there a clean way of closing system in python

Tags: python

So what I am wondering is this: Is there a way of being able to exit some python code without all of this appearing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\My Documents\Year 13\COMP4\trial.3.1.4.1.py", line 590, in <module>
    myApp.monitorInput()
  File "H:\My Documents\Year 13\COMP4\trial.3.1.4.1.py", line 578, in monitorInput
    self.close()
  File "H:\My Documents\Year 13\COMP4\trial.3.1.4.1.py", line 293, in close
    sys.exit()
SystemExit
```

This just looks as if it is an error but really all I am doing is exiting some code. I don't mind it appearing but it just doesn't look neat and good if it exists as an eror message.

Here is the area in my code where I exit the program that I am running:

```
def close(self):
    print ("pygame quit")
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

The main area where all this goes on:

```
def monitorInput(self):

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    RUNNING = True
    while RUNNING:

        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                RUNNING = False
                break

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    self.show_keyboard = not self.show_keyboard
                    self.show_panes = not self.show_panes

            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:

                textSelected = self.mouseDown()
                print(textSelected)

                if textSelected == "Keyboard":
                    self.createKeyboard()

                elif textSelected == "Boxes":
                    self.createWords()

                elif textSelected == "Set Phrases":
                    self.createPhrases()  

                elif textSelected == "OK":
                    self.okButton()

                elif textSelected != "Nothing selected":
                    if self.show_keyboard:
                        self.terminal.addText(textSelected)
                    else:
                        self.terminal.addWord(textSelected)

                # --- draws terminal to reflect the additions ---
                if self.show_terminal:
                    self.terminal.draw()
                    pygame.display.update()
                #end if

            #end if

        #end for


        pygame.display.update()

        # --- FPS ---

        clock.tick(60)

    #end while
    self.close()
```

Comment: btw how are you running your script?

Comment: Odd. `SystemExit` exceptions aren't usually supposed to be printed; they're just supposed to cause a normal program exit.

Comment: @WeaselFox What do you mean. I am running it using PyGame (I think that might be the answer to your question)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

how about simply exit:

```
exit(1)
```

Comment: If this was the answer, please mark it as the answer once stackoverflow allows you to. To guide future readers.

Comment: @user2128576 I think I have? It says I have on my computer.

Comment: @PythonNovice Please ignore my comment. The page must have not updated yet in my browser at my time of viewing.

Comment: Ok no worries. Aha. :)